# Why can't I add a modifier like Bevel to object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

This modifier doesn't work to me

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1deycZkqFSkDejuKELiqPivrWc_oWlR9H/view?usp=sharing)

My problem in image

[image]

Comment: do you mean that it doesn't work? Probably because it makes the faces overlap and the Clamp Overlap is enabled? Hard to say without some screenshots or without the file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: it didn't helped

Comment: See my edit, it looks like it helps

Comment: say me how i made all the same but it didn't work.....oh((((((

Comment: you need to select all in Edit mode and press M > Merge by Distance, I don't know where you fail

Comment: i don't know why it doesn't work

Comment: As John says, in the modifier try a low Amount value

Answer (score 4):

You have overlapping vertices, it prevents the bevel, select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*. In the modifier, use a low *Amount* value (here 0.8):

Result:

[image]

Comment: He also has a crazy setting for the bevel Amount in his image above (35.44 m). I used .01m and 3 segments and it works fine here.

Comment: oh yes you may be right